# Closed Form E[exp(x'Ax)]

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Is there a (general) closed form available for the following expression?

$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{x^{T}Ax}\right]$$
Where:
$$x=\left\{ x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{N}\right\} \sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\varSigma_{N}\right)$$
With the following symmetric matrices:
$$\varSigma_{N}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{21} & \ldots & \sigma_{N1}\\
\sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} & \ldots & \sigma_{N2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sigma_{N1} & \sigma_{N2} & \ldots & \sigma_{NN}
\end{array}\right)$$
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{21} & \ldots & a_{N1}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{N2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{N1} & a_{N2} & \ldots & a_{NN}
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Are the matrices diagonal?

Comment: Unfortunately not (

Comment: Ok, so they are symmetric.

Comment: yes that's correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using the [general solution of the Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization)
$$
\int\!d^nx\,\exp\Bigl(-\frac12 x^T A x\Bigr) = \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det A}}.$$

In your case, you we have that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{x^{T}Ax}\right]
= \sqrt{\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n \det \Sigma}} \int\!d^nx \exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma^{-1} x\Bigr) e^{x^T A x}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n \det \Sigma}} \int\!d^nx \exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2} x^T (\Sigma^{-1} -2 A) x\Bigr) .$$

The expectation value is convergent, if $\Sigma^{-1} -2 A$ is a positive definite matrix. In this case, we obtain the result
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{x^{T}Ax}\right] = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\det \Sigma\,\det(\Sigma^{-1}- 2 A)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det( I- 2  \Sigma A)}}\,.$$

Comment: This helps a lot! I needed this because Mathematica does handle these kind of functions well. Your shortcut provides me with great speedup!

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask if there is a way to compute $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{x^{T}Ax+b^{T}x+c}\right]$$ as efficiently? Note that c is a constant and:$$b=\left\{ b_{1},..,b_{N}\right\} $$

Comment: @Breugem: the trick is called "completing the square". One obtains the result: $$\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{x^T A x + b^T x + c} \right]  = \det{}^{-1/2}(I-2 A \Sigma^{-1}) \exp(c-1/4 b^T A^{-1} b).$$ Of course $A^{-1}$ should exist.

Comment: very useful! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps Im implementing this wrong, but could it be that there is a typo in the code? A computation in mathematica of $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{X^{2}}\right]$$  yields $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\sigma}}$$ but according to your formula it must be (if im right) $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2/\sigma}}$$. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I might have detected an error: In think the code should be: $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{x^{T}Ax}\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det\left(\Sigma\right)(2\pi)^{n}}}\int\!d^{n}x\exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}x^{T}\Sigma^{-1}x\Bigr)e^{x^{T}Ax}=..=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(I-2A\Sigma)}}$$. Please correct me if im wrong ;)

Comment: @Breugem: you are right, I somehow took $\Sigma$ to be the inverse of the variance. I will correct the post. Sorry for the confusion.